# Saving a Model and get it after save to use it as ForeignKey to create another Model

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following 2 models:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=35)

class ActionItem(models.Model):
    note = models.models.OneToOneField(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In other models(based on some conditions) I trigger an utility function that create a Note:

```
def create_note(target=None, action=None):

    note = Note(target=target, name=name).save()
    transaction.on_commit(
        ActionItem(note=note, target=target).save())
```

I get the following error:

```
null value in column "note_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, null).
```

If I use:

So, I presume the error appears because `save`, doesn't return anything.
I need the Note to pass it as a FK to ActionItem, an be sure it was saved.

Comment: The `.save()` does *not* return the object created.

Comment: Not related, but you're not using `on_commit` properly there; your ActionItem will be saved first because you call it within the parentheses, rather than passing the callable. You should define a function or lambda that does the creation, and pass that *without calling it* to on_commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.save()` method of a model does not return anything, hence your `note` variable is `None`, and as a result the creation of an `ActionItem` object gets a `None` for `note` reference, and thus raises na error.

We can solve it by using `Note.objects.create(..)` which `.saves()` and returns the object:

```
def create_note(target=None, action=None):
    note = Note.object.create(target=target, name=name)
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: ActionItem.object.create(note=note, target=target))
```

Alternatively, we can first construct the object, and then `.save()` it:

```
def create_note(target=None, action=None):
    note = Note(target=target, name=name)
    note.save()
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: ActionItem.object.create(note=note, target=target))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use create function instead of save function

```
def create_note(target=None, action=None):

    note = Note.objects.create(name=name)

    actionItem = ActionItem.object.create(note=note, target=target)
```